# python 3 if..elif won't print

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

For some dumb reason, I can't get my if..elif to print in python 3 but it somehow works in python 2. I'm not sure what I missed.

This is my if, elif

```
def encdec(userinput, machine, plaintext):
    if userinput == 1:
        print("-----------------------------------")
        print("Encoded:")
        enc = machine.encrypt(plaintext)
        print(enc)
        
    elif userinput == 2:
        print("-----------------------------------")
        print("Decoded:")
        dec = machine.decrypt(plaintext)
        print(dec)
```

This is my main using python 3's input function.

```
class main():

    print("Cryptography")
    print("[1] Encode")
    print("[2] Decode")


    userinput = input("Enter your choice: ")
    plaintext = input("Plaintext: ")
    
    
    rightkey = "SGLBIZHJMFTRXAVKNQPDWYCUOE"
    leftkey = "XLEMFHIWOVNYRUDQCJPASGBTKZ"

    if rightkey.isupper()==True:
        rightkey = rightkey.lower()

    if plaintext.isalnum()==True:
        import re
        plaintext = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+","",plaintext)

    
    cm = SaveSpaces(UpperCase(CryptMachine(Chao(), leftkey)))
    cm.set_alphabet(rightkey)
    encdec(userinput, cm, plaintext)
    
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Check the `type(userinput)`. It's not an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert userinput as int

```
userinput = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
```

or

```
if userinput=='1':
elif userinput=='2':
```

convert this

Comment: thank you, it worked! but can I ask also why my decode function has an error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Comment: @Hope Less If you have follow-up or more questions, then post a new question for each one. Each Q&A pair should focus on a *specific* problem, not make it a discussion for the entire code.

Comment: oh sorry, will post a new one